# Instruction pointer and function pointer constantness

Tags: c, function-pointers

I have the following piece of C code which prints the **rip** register and the address of a function foo. Running the executable multiple times results in the same values of **rip** and &foo being printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

void foo(int x) {
    printf("foo sees %d\n", x);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    uint64_t ip;
    asm("leaq (%%rip), %0;": "=r"(ip));
    printf("rip is 0x%016" PRIx64 "\n", ip);

    void (*fp)(int) = &foo;
    printf("foo is at offset %p\n", fp);
    (*fp)(10);        

    return 0;
}
```

Q1: Why does rip remain the same?

Q2: Will &foo remain the same, provided the binary and machine remain the same?

Q3: When can &foo change?

Background: I am trying to store the execution times of functions in a history table. I am thinking of using the function address to index into the table and calculate deviations from previous executions.

Answer (score 2):

Q1:

Depends on your platform.  Some platforms load your program into a virtual address space, so the exact same code will have the exact same virtual address for *foo* (assuming the program and the OS's loader don't change between runs, and the loader isn't one that randomizes the load address per the comments).  On other platforms that do not load your executable into a virtual address space, you may or may not get the same address depending on whether other programs have executed and/or terminated between runs.

Q2:

Don't count on it.  If *nothing* changes at all, you will have deterministic behavior (same address).  But there are many, many things that can change (again, dependent on the platform).

Q3:

They can change at any time on a platform that doesn't allocate a virtual address (as other processes start/continue doing work/terminate).  On a platform that does allocate a virtual address, they addresses can change if your program or related libraries change at all, if there is an OS patch that changes loader behavior, or probably due to other circumstances I'm not thinking of at the moment.

**Bottom Line**

Storing the address may work for your very specific case, but it's a fragile solution.

Comment: Thanks! Platform is always a Linux x86 (32 or 64-bit) SMP machine. Is the solution still too fragile?

Comment: You should not expect that a system that loads each process into its own address space will use the same address each time. A loader may load programs into different addresses, and this may be done different as a defense against malware. (Some malware exploits buffer overruns by using known addresses in memory to cause subroutine returns to branch to those addresses. Changing the addresses prevents that from working.)

Comment: @nandu you're likely to find things like command line arguments and/or the number of environment variables move things around in some cases.

Comment: All good points in the comments.  Indeed, some loaders randomize addresses for various reasons including but not limited to anti-malware.  Environment variables also can take additional memory depending on the OS (DOS I know allocated a fixed buffer, but I suppose modern OSes are more flexible).  The loader on his OS isn't randomizing the address (per the observed behavior) but I updated the answer for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is guaranteed.

The solution is to index using the function **name**, not its address (The C99 standard provides the `__func__` identifier). That way your index is guaranteed to remain the same across all changes in OS, compiler, options, and phase of the moon. Until you refactor the function name, of course :-)

Comment: Great C99 solution! Assuming non-C99, I will need to convert function address into function name. I was thinking about using the backtrace_symbols_fd function (man 3 backtrace) for this. Do you know of a better alternative?

Comment: Create an array of a struct mapping the function pointers to the respective strings (or numeric index right away!).

Comment: But since you state you have a Linux x86 box, you can rely on gcc or clang to support `__func__`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Linux you can use `dladdr()` to ask about symbols near places in memory. For example:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void foo() {
}

int main() {
  Dl_info info;
  void *test = foo; // Note: not standard C
  dladdr(test, &info);
  printf("closest symbol: %s in %s\n", info.dli_sname, info.dli_fname);
  return 0;
}
```

when compiled with:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra test.c -ldl -rdynamic
```

Correctly identifies the `void*` as `foo`, which will be correct no matter where `foo` gets loaded.